# Subjuntivo de 'traer'

Tags: subjuntivo

En las afirmaciones:

> 1. *Te dije que no lo **trajeras**.*
> 2. *Te dije que no lo **traigas**.*

¿Cuál es su interpretación?
Si tengo

> 1. *Te dije que no lo **trajeras*** = Igual lo traje.
> 2. *Te dije que no lo **traigas*** = Igual lo traigo.

¿Son correctas sus interpretaciones?

Answer (score 4):

Efectivamente.

Si digo «te dije que hagas algo», indico por el traslado al tiempo presente que aún queda tiempo por hacerlo. Podrías considerarlo meramente un recordatorio o bien algo que lo debes comenzar ya (porque el presente del subjuntivo ocupa un espacio tanto presente como futuro)

Si digo «te dije que hicieras/hicieses algo», indico que lo quería hecho para algún momento que se sitúa en el pasado. Perdiste la oportunidad de hacer lo que te pedí.